# Does `instance` variable cause poor performance?

Tags: reactjs

I used a `state` boolean variable `didApiCalled` to check whether the API gets called or not.

But I also wanted to use a `instance` variable for this usecase as instance variable didn't re-render. My colleague thinks this is a bad idea as this will cause some binding issue or it'll throw some error.

Comment: if it should not cause a re-render, then it might be better performance if it's out of state (avoiding unnecessary re-renders)... but what's it for if not needed in render?

Comment: If api is called then I will call some function which also calls setState

Comment: What about `shouldComponentUpdate` to prevent rerenders?

Comment: That is another way for this. But I just want to know whether we can use instance variable or not.

Comment: @anonymous_siva You can use an instance variable if you don't worry about it keeping its value when the component is unmounted and subsequently mounted as a different component with another data. You have to understand how components work. In some exception situations using an instance variable is a good idea (e.g. to attach an event listener when mounted and detach when unmounted) but those situtations are rare.

Comment: React apps are designed in such a way , where you can utilize instance variable to update the component. If you need to check with changes in your component, use setState, it will automatically rerender in all cases. You can possibly set state when API get called , which inturn can call function/ make changes which you may need